# cheap way to scale a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud, scalability, shared-hosting

I have an application, that is becoming big, but until now, its not giving me a good revenue. That means, short money to re-invest on that. In this scenario, i found a way to make a "cheap distributed rails" deployment.

I've got 4 VPS. All of them are in the same physical server. I added a load balance server running HAproxy in one dedicated VPS. There i pointed my virtual ip address where my domain name is associated. Behind this HAproxy i have more two VPS running my rails APP, passenger and memcache. Both apps servers are looking to the same database server, my 4th VPS. So with $44/month, i mounted a distributed environment. It won't be my final choice, but now, that the budget is short, is that a good way to deploy a rails application? Any pros or cons? It worth my $44/month?

Answer (score 0):

It may be more efficient to increase the resources on a single VPS and tune passenger to handle more memory and concurrent Rails instances.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Why do you think that it would be more efficient? 4 VMs in the same Physical server will bring more I/O than one powerful VM?

Comment: The I/O will really depend on the setup. But running a VM takes overhead, and you have a whole instance just running the proxy. You can have those resources just running your app.